# VBScript to find and move files automatically

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I've been tasked with trying to automate a task at work, because we've had issues lately with people remembering to do it.

In general, here's what I need a script to do:

1. Get the date of the previous day, in the format YYYYMMDD
2. Enter a folder with that given name
3. Search within all the folders underneath that location for 4 specific files
4. Copy those files to several different locations

The issue I'm having is that, for the 4 files I'm looking for, they're located in 2 different folders. 3 in 1, 1 in the other. The names of these folders changes daily, depending on what queue they got put into when generated by some other software. I need these files to be moved so that another script can be run on them. I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish this. Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: I've got a script that can pull the current date and subtract 1, and then enter that folder. After that point I've gotten stuck. My VBS is rather rusty, having not been used in a fairly long time, so I'm having difficulty remembering exactly what commands can do what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folders containing the interesting files are subfolders of your dated directory, you can use a nested loop:

```
  Dim sDFolder : sDFolder    = "..\data\20110105"
  Dim dicFiNa  : Set dicFiNa = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  dicFiNa("1.txt") = ""
  dicFiNa("3.txt") = ""
  dicFiNa("5.txt") = ""
  Dim oRDir     : Set oRDir  = goFS.GetFolder(sDFolder)
  Dim oSDir
  For Each oSDir In oRDir.SubFolders
      Dim oFile
      For Each oFile In oSDir.Files
          WScript.Echo "looking at", oFile.Path
          If dicFiNa.Exists(oFile.Name) Then
             WScript.Echo "found", oFile.Name, "will copy"
          End If
      Next
  Next
```

output:

```
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\whatever\6.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\whatever\5.txt
found 5.txt will copy
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\unknown\4.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\unknown\3.txt
found 3.txt will copy
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\puzzle\2.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\puzzle\1.txt
found 1.txt will copy
```

A full recursive walk would be a bit more complex, so say so, if you need it.

---

Just for fun: a recursive version:

```
  Dim sDFolder : sDFolder    = "..\data\20110105"
  Dim dicFiNa  : Set dicFiNa = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  dicFiNa("1.txt")  = ""
  dicFiNa("3.txt")  = ""
  dicFiNa("55.txt") = ""
  Dim oRDir     : Set oRDir  = goFS.GetFolder(sDFolder)
  walk oRDir, dicFiNa, "whatever you need to copy the files"

Sub walk(oDir, dicFiNa, vCargo)
  Dim oItem
  For Each oItem In oDir.Files
      WScript.Echo "looking at", oItem.Path
      If dicFiNa.Exists(oItem.Name) Then
         WScript.Echo "found", oItem.Name, "will copy"
      End If
  Next
  For Each oItem In oDir.SubFolders
      walk oItem, dicFiNa, vCargo
  Next
End Sub
```

output:

```
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\whatever\6.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\whatever\5.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\unknown\4.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\unknown\3.txt
found 3.txt will copy *
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\puzzle\2.txt
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\puzzle\1.txt
found 1.txt will copy *
looking at E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8750206\data\20110105\puzzle\deep\deeper\55.txt
found 55.txt will copy *
```

(*) as soon as the permission problem is solved.

Comment: Works great so far. Had to modify a few things to tweak it to how I wanted things, but going great. My only issue now is that when it actually tries to copy the file, I get a permission denied error. Any idea on a way to bypass that?

Comment: @YodaEXE: obviously, you can't copy a file, if it is used/locked or you(r process) isn't allowed to write to the destination. Doesn't the error message provide futher information? What kind of files do you work with?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work through VBS as I kept getting permissions errors, but I just modified it a bit to run a batch file that did the actual copying and now it works great. Thanks a lot!